# Calling a function in chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to call a function in the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` that returns a string that I will be sending it in `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`.

code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:var string1= ??? ;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(string1);"});
```

How do I do this . My function contains Javascript code that returns a string or an array of strings.

Some help would be appreciated.

Update:

```
function(array_of_Tabs) {
  var tab = array_of_Tabs[0];
  //tab.url; - url of the active tab

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'var test = document.body,text= test.textContent,bodyStart="<BODY",bodyEnd="</BODY>",regex=bodyStart+"(.*?)"+ bodyEnd,regexg = new RegExp(regex, "g"),match = regexg.exec(text);' + 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage(match);'});
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = request;
});
```

This should've worked according to what you told me, But doesn't . Why.?

And yes BTW I am not parsing pure html on the page it may be anything say  to  for that matter.

Comment: See my comment in **[your other identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298013/chromes-tabs-executescript-js-doesnt-work)**.

Answer (score 3):

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` has a third, optional argument that has access to the result of your injected code. E.g.

```
// In `background.js`:
...
const tab = ...
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    {code: 'const string1 = "Hello, world!"; return string1;'},
    resultArr => processString1(resultArr[0]));

function processString1(str1) {
  alert(`String1 = "${str1}"`);
}
```

If this does not cover your needs and you still want to use Message Passing:

```
// In `background.js`:
...
const tab = ...
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    {
      code: 'const string1 = "Hello, world!"; ' +
            'chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: string1});',
    });

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  if (msg.text !== undefined) {
    alert(`String1 = "${msg.text}"`);
  }
});
```

Comment: It does not work because you changed the code and introduced errors. I don't have any better advice to give than my comment in **[your other identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298013/chromes-tabs-executescript-js-doesnt-work)**.

Comment: I really don't find much help about injecting a file from the docs mate :(

Comment: It's OK. It would make the code more readable, but it wouldn't work anyway. Stop trying to parse HTML with regex, read about `textContent` read the Chrome Extension docs more carefully and you'll be good to go.

Comment: see I am not parsing html but some text on the page which can be any delimiter's instead of those tags.

Comment: I really don't understand why you don't want to admit that you are trying to parse HTML with RegEx, but it on't help you in any way. I don't have anything more to say. I believe you should post a new question, state as clear as possible what you are trying to achieve and hope for some good advice to follow.

Comment: how about the updated code.>??? `javascript:(function(){ 
var test = document.body; 
var text = test.textContent; 
var bodyStart="<BODY"; 
var bodyEnd="</BODY>"; 
var lim1=text.indexOf(bodyStart); 
var lim2=text.indexOf(bodyEnd); 
var printstr=text.substring(lim1-bodyStart.length,lim2+bodyEnd.length); 

})();` Now printstr has something like `"<body>....</body>"`

Comment: That event handler assignment looks wrong. Shouldn't it be `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function() {...})`?

Comment: @gkalpak, Why is `resultArr` always 1 item? When I return an array, the array is accessed using `resultArr[0][i]` wtf?

Comment: @Pacerier, as mentioned in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), this array contains _"the result of the script in every injected frame"_ (because you may inject the code/script in several frames in the specified tab). By default, the first item of the results array corresponds to the result of the code/script from the top-level frame of your tab, which is usually what you care about.